# Best DOM time to run jQuery AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I am building a WordPress AJAX plugin that pulls the Like count for a user from various Social media sites. The plugin uses one jQuery AJAX request to initially make the request to all the Social Media sites.

The initial call to all the different Social Media sites can be quite slow. After the initial call(s) the Like counts are cached in the WordPress database.

I am building a custom jQuery function to make the AJAX request and am wondering what is the best event to tie the AJAX function to.

**.ready**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code here
});
```

or 
**.load**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // code here
});
```

Comment: If it's being done on load, do it as early in the page lifecycle as possible, ie. `document.ready` as `window.load` doesn't fire until everything in the page is ready and is just adding delay.

Comment: `jQuery ajax` is asynchronous, so it won't effect the loading of the rest of the page, so you might as well start it as early as possible ( `$(document).ready`)

Comment: Thanks guys, both your comments make perfect sense. Will run it on load.

Comment: You can do it *before* `.ready()` fires...Why wait?

Comment: You really ought to launch the ajax call immediately and just process the result when the DOM is ready.  This will get your result into the page the fastest.  No need to wait to launch the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the deference between load and ready:
**ready:** executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
**load:** executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects

**Update:**
As said in the comments by @rnevius you can run the request without any DOM event, so you can execute the request as the script loads.

So the earliest as possible is to do this on `ready`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can make an AJAX request *before* `ready`. The DOM doesn't need to be loaded.

Comment: @mevius - I agree.  The earliest possible time to launch the ajax call is way, way before ready.

Answer (score 1):

You don't meet to wait for ready actually which does come before load , just put it in the head of the html after jquery is loaded synchronously. If you want everything async including loading jquery then you have to place it in ready.
Here is an article, there also many more like this one.
http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to wait until either the ready or load events occur to send your ajax call.  In fact, you will get your ajax result quicker if you don't wait.  What you do need to wait for is for the DOM to be ready before you can put the result into the page.

So, the fastest way to see the result is to launch the ajax call immediately (from the head section) and then in either `.ready()` or when the ajax call completes (whichever is last), you then put the results into your page.

You can do that with this in the `<head>` section, but after jQuery is loaded:

```
(function() {
    // set up a deferred for when the document is ready
    var docready = $.Deferred();
    $(document).ready(docready.resolve);

    // kick off your ajax call
    var p = $.ajax(...);

    $.when(p, docready).then(function(data) {
        // data[0] is your ajax result
        // and your page is ready to be modified
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use ready as per the reason given by vlio20 but you have the option of using load too.
It actually depends upon the requirement since the load waits for all the elements to load hence we prefer ready.